Packing True-sky assets for renderfarm
I'm trying to pack my file to send it for rendering on a renderfarm, but I'm having a problem with assets from the True-sky addon by True-VFX. I'm getting an error message about a file from this addon when using the pack resources option in Blender. I've also tried making all relations local and then packing resources again, and that didn't work either.
